# Unicode Icons for incomming vs outgoing

Tags: unicode, icons

I am searching a unicode icon to express "incomming" vs "outgoing".

[image: incomming-outgoing-sketch]

Some months ago I sketched above picture to ilustrate my idea.

I am not fixed to my idea, I just want some simple icon to express these two directions.

Is there a unicode icon which could be used?

If not, how to proceed, to update the unicode icon set?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a unicode icon which could be used?

Not really, no.  Although there are [*many* arrows](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/) available in Unicode, none of them really look quite like how you describe.

You might consider just using something simple like `↘` and `↗`.

> If not, how to proceed, to update the unicode icon set?

Create (or find) a custom font that has the glyphs you want, and then use it as needed.  Especially if you/it makes use of [Unicode private-use codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), which are designed for this kind of situation.